# Flip a table from a mysql query and output in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to invert a table in an output of php mysql. Running the below code prints all the header vertically and the all the data vertically below it.

```
Expected output :
Name -- xxx
DoB --- xxx
Gender - xxx
Email -- xxx
Phone -- xxx
Address - xx

<table id="myTable">
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>      
    <tr><th>DoB</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Gender</th></tr> 
    <tr><th>Email</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Phone</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Address</th></tr>                       

    <?php
        while ($report=$result->fetch_assoc())  
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$report['name']."</td>";                
        echo "<tr><td>".$report['dob']."</td>"; 
        echo "<tr><td>".$report['gender']."</td>"; 
        echo "<tr><td>".$report['email']."</td>"; 
        echo "<tr><td>".$report['phone']."</td>"; 
        echo "<tr><td>".$report['address']."</td>"; 
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that you have the table displayed vertically, and you want to flip this table to be displayed horizontally, **the solution** would be like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <?php
        $fields = $result->fetch_fields();
        foreach($fields as $field){
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $field->name . '</td>';
                while($report = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo '<td>' . $report[$field->name] . '</td>';
                }
                $result->data_seek(0);
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```